# Error when no certain data on JSON

Tags: c#, json, gridview, uwp

I have a JSON as follows:
[image: JSON]

In JSON above, the first data have "image_url" data, while the second data has no "image_url" data.

JSON is used in gridview. I have a problem, that is: if you do not have the "image_url" data on JSON, it will be in an error as below:

[image: Error Message]

XAML:

```
<GridView
                x:Name="itemGridView" Grid.Row="1"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemDetailScrollViewer"
                Margin="10,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                SelectionMode="None"
                IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="itemGridView_ItemClick"
                DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=itemListView}"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Height="300" Width="215" Margin="10,10,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#FF646464" BorderThickness="0.5">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Border x:Name="coverBox" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,0,0" Width="190" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0.5">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="images/IP-placeholder.png"/>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <Image x:Name="cover" Source="{Binding ImageURL}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" ImageOpened="Image_ImageOpened" Loaded="cover_Loaded" Loading="cover_Loading" DataContextChanged="cover_DataContextChanged"/>
                            </Border>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="id" Text="{Binding ID}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF8D8D8D" FontSize="17" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <StackPanel Height="25" Background="{x:Null}">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="title" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Normal" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="rating" Margin="10,5,10,0" Text="{Binding Rating}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF8D8D8D" FontSize="17" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                <StackPanel Margin="10,5,10,0" Height="40">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="address" Text="{Binding Address}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="phones" Margin="10,5,0,0" Text="{Binding Phone}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FFD47A22" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
```

Code:

```
try
                        {
                            loading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                            string urlPath1 = "http://.../results.json?module=listing&page=2&token=3f63-dc43-c8d5-eb45-8cbf-b72d-9d98-800f";
                            var httpClient1 = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                            var values1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                            {

                            };
                            HttpResponseMessage response1 = await httpClient1.GetAsync(urlPath1);
                            response1.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                            if (!response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
                                RequestException();
                            }
                            string jsonText1 = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            JsonObject jsonObject1 = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText1);
                            JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject1["data"].GetArray();

                            foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData1)
                            {
                                JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();

                                double id = groupObject2["id"].GetNumber();
                                string title = groupObject2["title"].GetString();
                                string address = groupObject2["address"].GetString();
                                string phone = groupObject2["phone"].GetString();
                                double rating = groupObject2["rating"].GetNumber();
                                string image_url = groupObject2["image_url"].GetString();

                                ListingClass file1 = new ListingClass();
                                file1.ID = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                                file1.Title = title;
                                file1.Address = address;
                                file1.Phone = phone;
                                file1.Rating = Convert.ToInt32(rating);
                                file1.ImageURL = image_url;

                                listingDatasource.Add(file1);
                            }
                            itemGridView.ItemsSource = listingDatasource;
                            busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
                        }

                        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                        {
                            busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
                            RequestException();
                        }
```

I would like if did not have the "image_url" data, the image is not displayed (only a border).
How to handle it?

Comment: Why don't you deserialize the JSON string directly to the collection of `ListingClass`class? That would set the value of missing properties to the default.

Comment: I using ListingClass to display on gridview. How to fix the code?

Comment: I have posted the answer below. I can provide better one if you can share part of actual JSON which you are dealing with.

Comment: Here is the link of JSON: http://indonesia-product.com/api/v1/results.json?module=event&page=2&token=3f63-dc43-c8d5-eb45-8cbf-b72d-9d98-800f (using the "data" JSON data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple solution for the exception you can check if the JsonObject has the key and the value associated with the key is null or not and set image url to string.Empty if it's null as following.

```
string image_url = groupObject2.ContainsKey("image_url") && groupObject2["image_url"] != null ? groupObject2["image_url"].GetString() : string.Empty;
```

Otherwise you can use following code to deserialize JSON to the collection of ListingClass.

You will have to add reference to Nuget Package "Newtonsoft.Json" for this code to work.

```
//Other code of calling service..
string jsonText1 = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText1);

var data = jsonObj["data"].ToString();

var listingDatasource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ListingClass>>(data);

itemGridView.ItemsSource = listingDatasource;
busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
```

Comment: I cannot install Newtonsoft.Json and display error message: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDOW56cHpBSzgyakU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How are you trying to install? It's a nuget package..... The error message you shared does not have much information about the cause of the error.

Comment: If it is becoming too complicated for you to use Newtonsoft.Json I have provided a simple solution in my answer just now. Please refer to it.

Comment: I tried to install it, but it was not successful installed and an error message like the one above.

Comment: I had to replace the string image_url = groupObject2["image_url"].GetString (); with string image_url = groupObject2["image_url"] == null ? string.Empty : groupObject2["image_url"].ToString(); But still an error message https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDTm1zQ2dmNVVBZE0/view?usp=sharing and all pictures become empty (appears only border) on a grid view

Comment: Note: In Json there who have "image_url" and some that do not have "image_url" (so "image_url" not null). Look at pictures of JSON that I post on my problem. If the JSON does not have "image_url", it would appear the border alone.

Comment: If you are checking for null then it should not throw NullReferenceError. Can you share the entire line of code? Are you using "JsonObject" from RestSharp ?

Comment: here the sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDU2tmUHh4eTN3OUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: chetan: can you help me to fix my project?

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to first check if the JsonObject contains key "image_url" or not and if it's value is null or not. If it contains the key and the value is not null the you try to get the string from it else let it be string.Empty. Try this.. this should solve the issue now.